# Change primary Key with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a database with 7 tables, among them all have relation.

In that web interface I need to modify all the records in the table including the field of the primary key, but I am never able to edit it and when I approach it it tells me that it is duplicated.

I attach a mega link with my sql and my php where I have everything to be able to modify it or I do not know how you want it to happen to you.

https://mega.nz/#!3NZjzIYR!dFqK-HNp-EIj-zGLB4tAbZWIIYVv8aegu8pbJJwOBRE

Comment: What, do you expect us to do it for you? Post your code here.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do and why would you need to change the primary key? In most cases the primary key should not need to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it is not working. Assuming you have a table like this:

```
Primary_Key  Name
1            Fred
2            Wilma
3            Pebbles
```

If you try to change Wilma's primary from "2" to "3", you will not be able to do so, because the primary key "3" is already in use by Pebbles. This is why you get a duplicate key error because you cannot have two primary keys of "3". You can only change the primary key to a new key that is not already in use such as "4".

Answer (score -1):

Index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'alumno.entidad.php';
require_once 'alumno.model.php';

// Logica
$alm = new Categoria();
$model = new CategoriaModel();

if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
switch($_REQUEST['action'])
{
    case 'actualizar':

        // Recupero el acronimo del campo hidden

        $alm->__SET('acronimo',   $_REQUEST['acronimo']);
        $alm->__SET('categoria',  $_REQUEST['categoria']);

        $update_results = $model->Actualizar($alm);
        header('Location: index.php');
        break;

    case 'registrar':
        $alm->__SET('acronimo',  $_REQUEST['acronimo']);
        $alm->__SET('categoria', $_REQUEST['categoria']);

        $model->Registrar($alm);
        header('Location: index.php');
        break;

   case 'eliminar':
        $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acronimo']);
        header('Location: index.php');
        break;

    case 'editar':
        // Recupero los datos por el acronimo
        // $obj_categoria es un objeto del tipo Categoria
        $obj_categoria = $model->Obtener($_REQUEST['acronimo']);
        break;
    default: 
        // MENSAJE 404 PARA CUANDO LA ACCION NO ES VALIDA
        header('HTTP/1.0: 404 Not Found');
        die('<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>');
}
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Anexsoft</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body style="padding:15px;">

    <div class="table table-striped">
        <div class="pure-u-1-12">

            <form action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="acronimo" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

                <table style="width:500px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="acronimo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="categoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach($model->Listar() as $r): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acronimo'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('categoria'); ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=editar&acronimo=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>">Editar</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=eliminar&acronimo=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
      <script>js/jquery.js</script>
      <script>js/bootstrap.min.js</script>
</body>
```

```
alumno.entidad.php

<?php
class Categoria
{
private $acronimo;
 private $categoria;

public function __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }
public function __SET($k, $v){ return $this->$k = $v; }
}


alumno.model.php

<?php
class CategoriaModel
{
private $pdo;

public function __CONSTRUCT()
{
    try
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1',                'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Listar()
{
    try
    {
        $result = array();

        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoria");
        $stm->execute();

        foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r)
        {
            $alm = new Categoria();

            $alm->__SET('acronimo', $r->acronimo);
            $alm->__SET('categoria', $r->categoria);
            $result[] = $alm;
        }

        return $result;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Obtener($acronimo)
{
    try
    {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE  acronimo = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
        $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $alm = new Categoria();

        $alm->__SET('acronimo', $r->acronimo);
        $alm->__SET('categoria', $r->categoria);

        return $alm;
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Eliminar($acronimo)
{
    try
    {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                  ->prepare("DELETE FROM categoria WHERE acronimo = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################
// CAMBIOS REALIZADOS
// - USO DE PARAMETROS NOMBRADOS EN EN METODO .execute()
// ##############################################################################################       
public function Actualizar(Categoria $data)
{
    try
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE categoria SET acronimo =:acronimo, categoria =:categoria WHERE acronimo=acronimo";

        return $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
             ->execute(
                array(
                    ':acronimo' => $data->__GET('acronimo'),
                    ':categoria' => $data->__GET('categoria')
                )
            );
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################

public function Registrar(Categoria $data)
{
    try
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria)
            VALUES (?, ?)";

    $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
         ->execute(
        array(
            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
            $data->__GET('categoria')
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This should be made part of your question, not an answer to your question. Edit your original question if you want to include code, but only include the relevant portions.